# How to fix upload files in React + Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, upload

I trying upload files to server, but I get error 500.

On frontend (React) I use axios:

```
class InputFile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedFile: null };
    this.handleUploadFile = this.handleUploadFile.bind(this);
    this.handleUpload = this.handleUpload.bind(this);
  }

  handleUploadFile(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
    });
  }

  handleUpload() {
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);
    axios
        .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload', data)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.statusText);
        });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input name='file' type='file' formEncType='multipart/form-data'
          onChange={this.handleUploadFile} multiple
        />
      </div>
      )
     }
    }
```

On backend (Node) I trying to save files in folder:

```
app.route('/upload')
    .post((req, res, next) => {
      const uploadFile = req.files.file;
      const fileName = req.files.file.name;

      uploadFile.mv(
          `uploadFiles/${fileName}`,
          (err) => {
            if (err) {
              return res.status(500).send(err);
            }

            res.json({
              file: `uploadFiles/${req.files.file.name}`
            });
          },
        );
    });
```

In fact I get error in console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

And **req.files** on backend is *undefined*. How can I fix it? It should be possible to upload one or more files at a time

> On frontend I use: "axios": "^0.18.0",
>
> On backend I use: "express-fileupload": "^1.0.0"

Comment: Did you apply `express-fileupload` middleware?

Comment: @doniyor2109 can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Here is simple example settup `express-fileupload` https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example#basic-file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with **directory path** on backend. I changed this:

```
`uploadFiles/${fileName}`,
```

to **full path** on my computer:

`/var/*/uploadFiles/${fileName}`,

Also I foggot to **add** this:

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload());
```